# how to view image in Django application

Tags: django, django-models, django-imagekit

I need to view only the image in HTML page.

Like : http://localhost:8000/media/project_name/imagenav.jpg

Example page : https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/c7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A/o.jpg

Thanks & Regards,
Mohamed Naveen

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

Your statics must be configured first.

```
{% load static%}
<br>
<img src = "{% static 'image name in static folder'%} " >
```

Check my site on heroku 
http://pyworldpy.herokuapp.com

Comment: I am not able to use the url in SLACK message

Comment: how host image in django

Comment: `reply = [{"blocks":[{"type": "section",    
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                                    "text": "HI"
                                },
                                "accessory": {
                                    "type": "image",
                                    "image_url": "https://9014a045.ngrok.io/vlab/image/get/sm.jpg",
                                    "alt_text": "alt text for image"
                                }
                            }
                        ]}]`

Comment: `{% load static%}
<img src="{% static "/icon/imagenav.jpg"%}" alt="parakeet">`

Comment: basically i need a image_url in django